# Slow CREATE times using Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm fairly new to Neo4j and Neo4jClient.

I'm trying to get some benchmarks for simple operations. 
I seem to be getting really slow inserts (CREATEs).
I recognize that this isn't the fastest way to do a batch insert, but it is more reflective of how my app will behave in real-life.

**Goal**: Add a Person object and link them to a "Super User/Person"

**Setup**:

1. In the Neo4j Console, I created one person and indexed the "myId" field
2. I'm running on an I5 MS SurfaceBook with 8g RAM. Windows 10.
3. VisualStudio 2015 Community with Update 2 RC2

**Result**: It is taking something like 7 seconds to add each 100 users and relationships. Here is some timing data from a stopwatch:
Added 200 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:00:35.5526979
Added 300 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:00:43.7953471
Added 400 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:00:51.0138293
Added 400 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:00:51.0139585
Added 500 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:00:56.0563539
Added 700 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:01:03.5407927
Added 800 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:01:08.0186756
Added 900 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:01:13.0089620
Added 900 Persons. Elapsed time = 00:01:13.0089809

**Code**:  This seems pretty straightforward. I just have a loop which creates a new person and then creates the relationship:

```
        //Create SuperNode
        int supermyId = 4000;// Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
        Person superPerson1 = new Person { name = "SUPER Name5 99900", born = 1903, myId = supermyId };

        int regularId = 0;
        Person regularPerson = null;

        graphClient.Cypher
            .Create("(person:Person {newUser})")
            .WithParam("newUser", superPerson1)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

        sw.Start();
        Parallel.For( 0, 5000, 
            index => {
                regularId ++;
                regularPerson = new Person() { name = "regular5 " + regularId, born = 1000, myId = regularId };
                graphClient.Cypher
                    .Create("(person:Person {regularPerson})")
                    .WithParam("regularPerson", regularPerson)
                    .ExecuteWithoutResults();

                graphClient.Cypher
                .Match("(superUser:Person)", "(regularUser:Person)")
                .Where((Person superUser) => superUser.myId == supermyId)
                .AndWhere((Person regularUser) => regularUser.myId == regularId)
                .Create("regularUser-[:SUPER5]->superUser")
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
                if (regularId % 100 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Added " + regularId + " Persons. Elapsed time = " + sw.Elapsed);
                }
            });
```

**Questions**:

1. Does this seem like normal speed for these operations?
2. Any thoughts on how I can speed this up?

Comment: Record-at-a-time transactions are slow-  if you can batch a number of record / relationship updates into a single transaction it'll go faster.

Answer (score 0):

So this comes down to how you create your nodes, the best approach is to create the `regularPerson` nodes in one shot first:

```
var regularPersons = new List<Person>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    //Generate users here
}
```

and with that pass it in to `Neo4j` using the [`Unwind`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html) keyword. This allows you to pass in whole collections.

Now, the other thing you're doing is running two queries for every addition - one to add the person, two to join to the `superUser`, we can compress that into 1 query which will run faster.

So, (and I'm not typing this on a computer, so forgive errors), create your `superUser` as you do, in one query, and then:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(su:Person)")
    .Where((Person su) => su.myId == supermyId)
    .Unwind(regularPersons, "rp")
    .Create("(p:Person {rp})-[:SUPER5]->(su)")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

As I said - I can't test this at the moment, but give it a whirl and experiment a bit to see how it works, generally, you *should* see this generate 5000 a lot faster than you did have it.

---

This is my working code, adding 5000 nodes in 1.3 seconds:

```
void Main()
{
    var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data/"));
    graphClient.Connect();

    var supermyId = 4000;
    Person superPerson1 = new Person { name = "SUPER Name5 99900", born = 1903, myId = supermyId };

    graphClient.Cypher
            .Create("(person:Person {newUser})")
            .WithParam("newUser", superPerson1)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

    var regularPersons = new List<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        regularPersons.Add(new Person { name = $"Person_{i}", born = 1900+(i%100), myId = i + 4000 });
    }

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    graphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(su:Person)")
        .Where((Person su) => su.myId == supermyId)
        .Unwind(regularPersons, "rp")
        .Create("(p:Person {born: rp.born, myId: rp.myId, name:rp.name})-[:SUPER5]->(su)")

        .ExecuteWithoutResults();

    Console.WriteLine($"Took {(DateTime.Now - now)} to add");
}

public class Person
{
    public int myId { get; set;}
    public int born { get;set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That all sounds very logical.  I'll test it in a few minutes and post the results

Comment: Update <br>

Refactoring the code to do each step in separate loops yields:<br>

Time to create Super User = 00:00:00.2573741 <br>
Time to create 5000 people in memory = 00:00:00.0068036 <br>
Time to add 5000 people to db = 00:02:31.0355261 <br>
Time to add 5000 relationships = 00:01:04.9076105 <br>

In many use cases these can be combined. But, in many, they can not. For example, the canonical Twitter example- A user joins (db insert) and then decides to waste their time by following a Kardashian (add relationship). <br>
This seems really slow.Is this consistent with other peoples experiences

Comment: Can you put a gist of your code somewhere - it shouldn't take 2 mins + to add 5000 entries to the db, I have a test which adds 100,000 in ~ 26 seconds, so that seems very slow.